# Background for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am quite new in the SpriteKit development and I am trying to develop my first game.

I have implemented some edges (to avoid the ball going out of the screen) using the visual Scene editor (GameScene.sks) and I had to specify the size of the Scene (640x960).
Now, using the code, I would like to change the background according to the device width/height (because I cannot limit to 640x960).

So, I need to use:

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.Fill
```

In order to stretch the edges of the scene for different devices

BUT

I would like the backgrounds to be in scale mode 1

Is that possible at all?

This is the code I am using to set up a different background for each device:

```
if(skView.bounds.width == 768.0) {

     var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg_768.jpg")
     let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)
     background.size.width = skView.bounds.width
     background.size.height = skView.bounds.height
     background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(skView.frame), CGRectGetMidY(skView.frame))
     scene.addChild(background)


} else {
  //set others backgrounds
}
```

But if the scene get stretched they get stretched too..!
Is there a way to avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: in few words, I want the scene and the background to fill the screen. The scene could be stretched with scaleMode but I don't want the background to be stretched.

Comment: You could try to set the background on the view controller holding the SKScene instead of creating it with SpriteKit.

Comment: @Skoua thank you, I gonna try that now

Comment: if you want the image to not scale, then you need to adjust the size of your scene at run time,  you do not want to scale it

Comment: What you may think about doing,  is creating a node i side your scene at the desired width and height,  and scale that node to fill your screen.  This will get you a bg that is not scaled, as well as a play area that is scaled.  Thats all i can think of if doing 100% spritekit